# Stylecop: getting too many errors like SA1400 when using a parent settings file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, stylecop

I have a (company-given) stylecop settings file with a handful of rules.

This I placed into the parent folder for my project (test project, local, no source control - stylecop settings still say "Merge with settings file found in parent folders").

When running Stylecop (4.7.42, Rescan All), I get several warnings like SA1400, SA1200 and so on, that I have not defined.

On the other hand, I have

```
<Analyzer AnalyzerId="Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.MaintainabilityRules">
  <Rules>
    <Rule Name="ArithmeticExpressionsMustDeclarePrecedence">
      <RuleSettings>
        <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">True</BooleanProperty>
      </RuleSettings>
    </Rule>
  </Rules>
  <AnalyzerSettings />
</Analyzer>
```

and

```
i = i * 2 + 3 * 6;
```

and get no warning for that. (Rule explanation: http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1407.html . Actually, setting True or False here results in no message.)

Also, when opening the settings editor, all settings are checked, though I only specify a few in my settings file.

I assume my settings file has little to do with what Stylecop reports?!

How to fix?

Comment: Your assumption that *only* the rules in the settings file are checked is just wrong.  Talk to whomever created the settings file in your company to check that it is okay to suppress messages yourself.

Comment: Well.. I did wonder about what "merge" means - actually, I want only the ones from the "main" settings file. Are there - per default - other rules active that then get "merged"? Where to see, how to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13434198/1505426

---

**Copied from linked answer:**

By default your settings files are merged into parent settings, and this could be causing you some issues. Try stopping the merging at the solution root by adding the following setting:

```xml
<GlobalSettings>
    <StringProperty Name="MergeSettingsFiles">NoMerge</StringProperty>
</GlobalSettings>
```

This will ensure that StyleCop acts the same on all development and build machines, regardless of the settings configured higher up the hierarchy (such as the one in the StyleCop application folder). However if you do this, make sure you copy all the required settings from the files no longer being merged.

Comment: Well.. I do not have any stylecop setting further up the hierarchy, so no, that should not be it. (The only other file I have is the one that seems to be auto-generated once I open the stylecop setting through the VS-context menu. That one is mostly empty, though (only containing the version infomration 105).

Comment: Did you install StyleCop? ie - is there a settings file in `Program Files` that is getting merged in (happens by default)?

Comment: So I could delete the default file?! (And yes, I did install StyleCop.)

Comment: I personally wouldn't as it will get replaced when you upgrade StyleCop, it may be essential for other projects, and you'd have to delete it off every machine you use (eg, build servers, other developers machines, etc). The recommended approach would be to stop merging at your file in the parent folder. This can either be done by updating the settings file directly, or via the settings dialog.

Comment: With my last test, everything worked (though I did not change anything I would think to be responsible). Anyway, many thanks and I will keep the global settings file in mind, just in case.